# unable to open Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) file in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gimp

I have many .eps files in a folder . I just want them to see how it looks. So i tried to open .eps file using document viewer it doesnot open. Again i tried through gv file.eps still it gives error like undefined Obj.....again when i tried to open through gimp file.eps there is also some problem like opening failed: Could not interpret PostScript file. I donot know why such types of problem exist in ubuntu 20.04(may be library problem). If it is required to install some extra packages let me know. I hope some solutions from experts side. Thanks.

Comment: it is the output of xfig software....i think it is not corrupted

Comment: It seems Xfig is able to import eps files. Were you able to successfully open/import the files with Xfig?

Comment: What does `file *.eps` tell you?